# Are free group&product the hardest free object&product to construct? And why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

The free objects I know are free group and free module. It is weird that even though the structure of module is more complex than that of group, the construction of free group is much harder than that of free module. (One needs to prove tedious lemmas to construct free group&product while the construction of fee module is very direct).

Now, I'm curious what's the hardest free object to construct and why that is the hardest one.

Comment: I don't think that the free group is harder to construct than a free module. You have to keep in mind that at the point you construct a free module, you probably heard already a lot about groups in general.

Comment: @Dan When constructing a free group on a set $A$, one needs to define $A^{-1}$ and words and reduced words then define an operation $a\ast b$ case by case ($b$ is empty, the first term of $b$ is (not) the inverse of the last term of $a$). However, free module can be directly constructed as $R^A$.

Comment: Not sure what tedious lemmas are required, the way I construct a free group is pretty simple.

Comment: @MattSamuel Not sure of the name of a trick, but both Lang and Rotman uses that trick. That is, to show associativity, there is a trick to view the juxtaposition of a single element in the front of a word as a permutation.

Comment: Why bother defining reduced words? Just define product to be concatenation and take equivalence classes under replacement rules of the form $(a,a^{-1})\equiv (a^{-1},a)\equiv ()$.

Comment: I think this is very opinion based. Free group is elementary in group theory. When you do modules you have already developed the theory, so you can use it and define objects such as $R^A$. You usually would need to also check stuff there. So if you want to explain a beginner, say freshman, in mathematics both objects, do you still think that the free group would be harder?